# Magento 2 - Delete Tierprices of products programmatically

Tags: php, magento-2.3

I tried several ways to remove tierprices and looked they were performed well with no issues.
But there are no changes in products and the tierprices are still remain.
Please recommend any solution for this please.

Comment: Provide some sample query of what you have tried please.

Comment: I didn't use any queries but built-in functions to remove tier prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$connection = $this->resource->
  getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);

$sql = 'DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` 
       WHERE `value_id` = ' . $price['price_id'];

$connection->query($sql);
```

We can remove tierprices directly via database by running query.